# How to order and divide up "Invited journal articles", "Journal articles", and "Conference articles" on a CV?

Tags: publications, computer-science, cv, invited-paper

I recently presented a paper at a conference, and it appeared in the proceedings of the conference. I have now been invited to submit an extended version of the paper to a special issue of a journal. This issue will contain the top papers from the conference (but not all papers that appeared in the proceedings). This is relatively common practice in my field of computer science.

I already have listed some journal articles on my CV that were submitted without invitation and accepted. Assuming this most recent article is accepted to the journal special issue, would it make sense to divide my publications list into 'invited' and 'regular' papers?

Specifically, I am considering two options for headings:

1. "Invited journal articles", "Journal articles", "Conference articles" (i.e. split up)
2. "Journal articles", "Conference articles" (i.e. leave combined)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I cite an invited paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14059/how-should-i-cite-an-invited-paper)

Comment: How is that a duplicate? The linked question is about citing an invited paper in a research article, not about how to list it in a CV.

Comment: Citation and listing things on a CV are quite similar, but I see your point. The title of the question also seems to have been edited, which makes it less like the one I found.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not in computer science, so I'm not sure if these three headings would be a standard everyone adheres to. Still, generally speaking, you have some freedom in how to organize a CV. However, splitting a section into two doesn't look great if you don't have enough stuff to put under the new headings. Instead of making a new heading for a single invited journal article, I would suggest leaving it as one section, and marking articles to highlight noteworthy aspects (e.g. invited, won best paper award, featured on cover page, etc.).